# How to match digits in perl glob

Tags: regex, perl, glob

```
$dir_path = (-d ("./abc/dir-\d.\d.\d")) ?
            glob("./abc/dir-\d.\d.\d/my-dir*") : "my-dir-doesnot-exists";
```

is this a valid glob option? can I use \d to match numbers in the dir path ?

$dir_path should get "./abc/dir-#.#.#/my-dir/some_dir_name" if "./abc/dir-#.#.#" exists (where # is any digit) else "my-dir-doesnot-exists" string

Comment: 1. I didn't want to add glob inside -d, edited the code now. 2. got it thanks. 3. I rephrased the question now, please see if it clarifies. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling both instances of `glob` in scalar context (but not as an iterator) which is very wrong. For example,

```
 my $foo = glob("a");
 my $bar = glob("a");
 say $foo // "[undef]";    # a
 say $bar // "[undef]";    # [undef]
```

The glob language is completely different than the regex language. `\d` won't work, but `[0123456789]` would.

```
my @dir_paths = glob("./abc/dir-[0123456789].[0123456789].[0123456789]/my-dir*");

die "No match!"         if !@dir_paths;
die "Too many matches!" if @dir_paths > 1;

my $dir_path = $dir_paths[0];
```

Comment: ok i see. `\d\d` could translated to `[0123456789][0123456789]` . but howto translate `\d+` to glob?

Comment: @SL5net. You can't. (That would generate and endless list)

Comment: ok. Then may \d{1,5} creates a ending list of 5 lines and may works?

Comment: @SL5net, `foo\d{1,5}` would be `foo[0123456789] foo[0123456789][0123456789] foo[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] foo[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] foo[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]`, but maybe `foo[0123456789]*` will be sufficient?

Comment: (I was wrong about "That would generate and endless list". While `{}` generates, `[]` matches.)

Comment: sufficient in most cases. its not the same meaning. therfore today i written a gulp preprocessor placed on github (now only windows os)

Comment: @SL5net, Why? Just use a regex match. Is not like using a glob pattern reduces system or disc accesses over a regex match.

Comment: then it was probably useless that i have genarated https://github.com/sl5net/gitignore_preprocessor today. but how could i use regEx inside inside a .gitignore file